# Inserting multiple elements into product grid cells with unique css (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, javascript, grid, html

I'm wondering how to insert many html elements into a cell in the product grid. I have an HTML template that serves style and other attributes via a JavaScript component, but I can only insert one HTML element into the cell.

Is it possible to insert multiple HTML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not be the most optimal answer, I decided to mimic what the thumbnail component does in module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns thumbnail.js and /module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/cells/thumbnail.html.

I'm using a similar js file to build a row of `<p>` elements with css and insert into a `<div>`.

```
<div class="icons" html="$col.getIcons($row())"/>
```